Rider remote development on MacOs with Windows vm
I want to work with .Net Framework 4.8 app using my Mac. Obviously this framework isn't supported outside of Windows ecosystem, therefore I have Windows VM (Virtual Machine) and I could work directly on the VM, but it would be isolated from other apps I host on Mac.
Ideally I would like to enable Remote Development and work from my IDE (JetBrains Rider) and map ports between machines, so I can access the app directly from my Mac.
Documentation so far says a pre-requisite is a system with Linux when it comes to agent, other than that it would be ideally what I need:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Remote_development_overview.html
Is there any workaround to make sure it works between Mac and Windows?

Remote development with hosting on Windows is not yet supported, unfortunately. But we are working on it and hope to deliver it soon.
There is the feature request on our tracker and an update from the development team: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-27/Remote-development-host-should-be-available-on-macOS-and-Windows#focus=Comments-27-9681059.0-0
Have a nice day!
